# Does Service Fabric maintain a separate copy of static class per service?

Tags: c#, static, azure-service-fabric

In my **service fabric cluster**, I have **two** services, service 1 and service 2. I have a common **static logger** class which is in its own project. While setting **static properties** of static logger class from both the services, it appears that each service (service 1, service 2) is maintaining its **own copy**. Can any one please elaborate the behavior here?

Comment: They are running in separate processes,.maybe even on different machines so it seems completely logical to me. Not sure what you expect.

Comment: [This info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-hosting-model) should help.